# Tornado server route with a dash at the start

Tags: python, tornado

I have a quick question. I have this following mapping in tornado.

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
   (r"/", MainHandler),
   (r"/get_value/([a-zA-Z\-0-9\.]+)", ValueHandler),
])
```

How can I map a route like this http://example.com/get_value/-13932392323 to this? (right now 500 internal server error) Please make note of the first character which is a dash/hyphen. that is the important thing. we finally want to map all these three patterns into it

```
http://localhost/get_value/387745745464

http://localhost/get_value/-357897845445

http://localhost/get_value/eyuer334eyu-3745ert446565ss-336rytuy45-sgsfgfa445fdf
```

Is it possible. If yes, how can I define the routes? (with the current definition the first and the third are happening. I want the second to happen also)

Please help

Comment: what is the reason for the 500 error that you get?

Comment: That regex already matches all three example patterns, and correctly calls the `ValueHandler` with the value after `/get_value/`. The 500 error is probably unrelated. What's the Traceback that shows up on the server-side?

Comment: I do not have the trace back with me now. I can give it to you on Monday only.

Comment: This should work. Perhaps your code is not able to handle the second case properly. In fact, if Tornado was failing to match the route, it would throw a 404 Not Found instead of 500.